# No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to play around with a custom object detection model that builds of a pretrained model. All I want is for my model is to detect a specific logo in a picture. The problem is, the guide that I am following is having problems with the libraries.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer

trainer = DetectionModelTrainer()
trainer.setModelTypeAsYOLOv3()
trainer.setDataDirectory(data_directory="/content/drive/MyDrive/Logo_Model2/")
trainer.setTrainConfig(object_names_array=["logo"], batch_size=4, num_experiments=122, train_from_pretrained_model="/content/drive/MyDrive/pretrained-yolov3.h5")
trainer.trainModel()
```

My error is coming when I import imageai.Detection.Custom import DetectionModelTrainer. I am doing this on google colab and I checked the versions and they seem to be all up to date.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'
```

Any ideas? I have looked around stack for similar problems yet I haven't been able to resolve my issue. It doesn't seem to be a tensorflow problem since I am able to build my models just fine until I add imageai.

Comment: What version of tensorflow are you running?

Comment: tf version: 2.8.0

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be an issue with the latest `tensorflow==2.8.0`. [git issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/53144)

For now, you can revert back to the older version of tensorflow

```
pip install tensorflow==2.7
```

And upgrade imageAI :

```
pip install imageai --upgrade
```